# R generate label with whitespaces

Tags: r

I try to generate a label with superscript and therefore using **parse**. I seem to cannot use whitespaces, this works:

```
GTVol <- 1:10
measuredVol <- 1:10
dat <- data.frame(GTVol, measuredVol)
ggplot(dat, aes(GTVol, measuredVol)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(slope=1) +
  xlab(parse(text='HarvestedVolume(m^3)')) + 
  ylab("QSM Volume (m^3)")
```

but this is not working:

```
GTVol <- 1:10
measuredVol <- 1:10
dat <- data.frame(GTVol, measuredVol)
ggplot(dat, aes(GTVol, measuredVol)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(slope=1) +
  xlab(parse(text='Harvested Volume (m^3)')) + 
  ylab("QSM Volume (m^3)")
```

giving me the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = "Harvested Volume (m^3)") : 
  <text>:1:11: unexpected symbol
1: Harvested Volume
```

Comment: @akrun done so, good point for minimal example, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the space character by adding `~`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(GTVol, measuredVol)) + 
  geom_point() + 
   geom_abline(slope=1) +
   xlab(parse(text='Harvested~Volume~(m^3)')) + 
   ylab("QSM Volume (m^3)")
```

-output

[image]

---

Or use `gsub` for dynamic replacement

```
  ...
   xlab(parse(text=gsub("\\s+", "~", 'Harvested Volume (m^3)'))) + 
   ...
```

Comment: Voted your answer up, but accepted the answer using expression instead of parse, cause I think its more correct. Indeed if you read my question I query an answer for parse, but appreantly my assumption was wrong when posting the question. 

I will shorten my question, so the accepted answer is still in agreement

Comment: @JanHackenberg that is fine.  I think `expression` or `bquote` are the right way.  I was also confused why you used `parse`.

Comment: Cause I just use R nowadays in my free time and lack of professional experience here. I wanted superscript in my label and parse was found when searching for the solution. Now I have best of both worlds.

Answer (score 5):

`plotmath` doesn't need `parse`, the rigth ways are with `expression` (below) or `bquote`.

```
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(dat, aes(GTVol, measuredVol)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1) +
  xlab(expression(Harvested ~ Volume ~ (m^3))) + 
  ylab(expression(QSM ~ Volume ~ (m^3)))
```

[image]